# How to resolve exoplayer error : AAPT: error: attribute fastforward_increment not found?

Tags: android-studio

Firstly I added the exoplayer dependency to my build. After that I made a xml layout with a custom controller and then I wanted to add **app:fastforward_increment** & **app:rewind_increment**. But every time I try to build it throws this error message :

> AAPT: error: attribute fastforward_increment not found.

I tried to resolve this issue by adding the other dependecies as they were suggesting in one of the forums but it didn't work. Do you know what's causing the issue and how to solve it?

[image: XML file]

[image: Build dependencies]

Comment: Have a look at the second bullet under the UI section for version 2.15.0: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/2a88f0fb295ff5b56e6fbcbe7e91bdf922cbae13/RELEASENOTES.md#2150-2021-08-10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The functions **app:fastforward_increment** & **app:rewind_increment** were removed in the version 2.15.0 and replaced by **setSeekBackIncrementMs** and **setSeekForwardIncrementMs** in SimpleExoPlayer.Builder. So instead of changing this value in xml file, now you have to change it programatically:

```
SimpleExoPlayer.Builder builder = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(context);
builder.setSeekBackIncrementMs(10000);
builder.setSeekForwardIncrementMs(10000);
SimpleExoPlayer simpleExoPlayer = builder.build();
```

Answer (score 1):

According to @Kristian answer, **app:fastforward_increment** and **app:rewind_increment** were removed. You can set like this:

```kotlin
val player = ExoPlayer.Builder(this)
            .setSeekBackIncrementMs(10000)
            .setSeekForwardIncrementMs(10000)
            .build()
```

Answer (score 0):

In the new version `com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.17.1` of Exoplayer, I deleted the parts in XML and added in the code part.

Xml:

```kotlin
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.StyledPlayerView
        android:id="@+id/playerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        argType:resize_mode="fixed_width"
        argType:show_buffering="when_playing"
        argType:show_fastforward_button="true"
        argType:show_next_button="false"
        argType:show_previous_button="false"
        argType:show_rewind_button="true"
        argType:show_subtitle_button="true"
        argType:use_artwork="true"
        argType:use_controller="true">
    </com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.StyledPlayerView>
```

Code:

```kotlin
playerView = ExoPlayer.Builder(this)
            .setSeekForwardIncrementMs(10000)
            .setSeekBackIncrementMs(10000)
            .build()
```

It worked flawlessly.